# skip one directory in "PHP_SELF"

Tags: php

```
<?php
 echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
?>
```

returns /directory/page/about.php
but how to get the result like this: /page/about.php ?
How to skip one directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
$full = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$ans = substr($full, strpos($full, "/", 1));
```